# Rolling Year Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I have a Google sheet where I would like a score based on a rolling year figure.

I have managed to do these separately using the formulas:

```
=query(A2:B," where A >= date '"&TEXT(today()-E1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
```

and

```
=(COUNTIF(H2:H15, "<>")*COUNTIF(H2:H15,"<>"))*(SUM(H2:H15))
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way these two could be combined so I just get the score.

Here is a [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C5aYp-8IkwJs8Fj_lB4JUQiGEifXN2Ucgw3K4-7RN74/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace both your formulas with this single one:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>(TODAY()-E1)-1))*POWER(COUNT(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>(TODAY()-E1)-1)),2)
```

Functions used:

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en-GB)
- [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en-GB)
- [POWER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093433?hl=en-GB)

---

#### *Pro tip*

Use the following formula without the need of an extra cell. It also **takes into account leap years**.

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>(TODAY()-(TODAY()-(EDATE(TODAY(),-12))))-1))*POWER(COUNT(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>(TODAY()-(TODAY()-(EDATE(TODAY(),-12))))-1)),2)
```

- More about [EDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is great!